# Writing several object values from a Arraylist to Console

Tags: c#, object, arraylist, console-application

Im writing a console application and i got a problem with writing all the objects property values into the console. I got a class that with all the propertys but i cant reach them as i do with a normal list. For example, a normal list loop could be like this with propertys examples (carBrand), and list name Cars.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Cars.Length; i++)
{
     Console.WriteLine(Cars[i].carBrand)
}
```

But for a ArrayList this doesnt seem to work. Why is that? Ive been looking around and for different methods without getting anything good out from it...

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        int menyval;
        ArrayList bilar = new ArrayList();
        Bil nybil = new Bil();
        string ägareefter;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nVälkommen till Dimmans Bilrace!");
            Console.WriteLine("Vi har {0} bilar i race just nu.", nybil.IRace);
            Console.WriteLine("\nVälj något alternativ i menyn nedan, klicka sedan ENTER:");
            Console.WriteLine("\n1. Lägg till en bil först.");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Lägg till en bil sist.");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Lägg till en bil efter en annan bil.");
            Console.WriteLine("4. Visa alla bilar i listan.");
            Console.WriteLine("0. Avsluta programmet.");
            Console.Write("\nDitt val:");
            menyval = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (menyval)
            {
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Programmet kommer nu avslutas. Tryck på valfri knapp.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nLägg till en bil först. Skriv in det som efterfrågas och avsluta med ENTER.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange ägarens namn:");
                    nybil.Ägarnamn = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange tillverkarens namn:");
                    nybil.Tillverkarnamn = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange modellens namn:");
                    nybil.Modellnamn = Console.ReadLine();

                    bilar.Insert(0, nybil);
                    nybil.LäggTillBiliRace(1);
                    Console.WriteLine("Nu har bilen lagts till i racet. Klicka på valfri knapp för att fortsätta.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nLägg till en bil sist. Skriv in det som efterfrågas och avsluta med ENTER.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange ägarens namn:");
                    nybil.Ägarnamn = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange tillverkarens namn:");
                    nybil.Tillverkarnamn = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Ange modellens namn:");
                    nybil.Modellnamn = Console.ReadLine();

                    bilar.Add(nybil);
                    nybil.LäggTillBiliRace(1);

                    Console.WriteLine("Nu har bilen lagts till i racet. Klicka på valfri knapp för att fortsätta.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nLägg till en bil efter en annan bil. Skriv in det som efterfrågas och avsluta med ENTER.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Följande bilar har vi:");

                    for (int i = 0; i < bilar.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("[Bil " + i + ": " + "Ägare = " + ((Bil)bilar[i]).Ägarnamn + ", "
                           + "Tillverkare = " + ((Bil)bilar[i]).Tillverkarnamn + ", Modell = " +
                           ((Bil)bilar[i]).Modellnamn + "]");
                    }

                    Console.Write("\nAnge namnet på ägaren som du vill placera den nya bilen efter:");
                    ägareefter = Console.ReadLine();
                        break;

                case 4:
                    if (bilar.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nVisar alla bilar i listan:");

                        for (int i = 0; i < bilar.Count; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("[Bil " + i + ": " + "Ägare = " + ((Bil)bilar[i]).Ägarnamn + ", "
                               + "Tillverkare = " + ((Bil)bilar[i]).Tillverkarnamn + ", Modell = " +
                               ((Bil)bilar[i]).Modellnamn + "]");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nListan innehåller inga bilar än. Klicka på valfi knapp för att komma till startmenyn");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Fel! Ange en siffra mellan de angivna värdena som finns. Tryck valfri knapp för att fortsätta.");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
            }
        } while (menyval != 0);
    }
}
```

}

Class code:

```
class Bil
{
    private string _ägarNamn;
    private string _tillverkarnamn;
    private string _modellnamn;
    private int _iRace;
    ArrayList billista = new ArrayList();

    public Bil()
    {
        _ägarNamn = "";
        _tillverkarnamn = "";
        _modellnamn = "";
    }

    public Bil(string ägarnamn, string tillverkarnamn, string modell)
    {
        _ägarNamn = ägarnamn;
        _tillverkarnamn = tillverkarnamn;
        _modellnamn = modell;
    }

    public string Ägarnamn
    {
        get { return _ägarNamn; }
        set { _ägarNamn = value; }
    }

    public string Tillverkarnamn
    {
        get { return _tillverkarnamn; }
        set { _tillverkarnamn = value; }
    }

    public string Modellnamn
    {
        get { return _modellnamn; }
        set { _modellnamn = value; }
    }

    public int IRace
    {
        get { return _iRace; }
        set { _iRace = value; }
    }

    public void LäggTillBiliRace(int i)
    {
        IRace += i;
    }
```

Best Regards.

Comment: Why not? What's the problem?

Comment: Is this a non generic `ArrayList`?

Comment: It is a non generic ArrayList.

Comment: The problem is that i just cant find the properties by writing list[i].propertyname.. The propertyname isnt there. Cant find any by intellisense. So i cant list any properties at all..

Comment: You need to use `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArrayList is a non generic type and so all the elements in it are objects.
You should cast the ArrayList first:

```
foreach (var car in cars.Cast<Car>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.carBrand)
}
```

Comment: I got the same problem with this solution as with the others. If i have more than one object in the ArrayList, the loop writes the same value for every property in the list.

Comment: The variables are on swedish, sorry for that. But the code is there now.

Comment: @MarcusPersson It's because you only ever create one instance of `Bil` which, since it's a class, is a reference type. Each time you're inserting an instance into your `bilar` collection, it's the same instance, so you end up with a bunch of entries in the list referencing the same object.

Comment: Replaced the object instance into the do-while loop and it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Since `ArrayList` is not generic, the compiler doesn't know what kind of objects are in that list. To access the properties, you'll have to cast them:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Cars.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((Car)Cars[i]).carBrand);
}
```

This works if you're sure that each and every object inside that ArrayList is a `Car`. If it's not, this will blow up. You can circumvent that, but I'd suggest you use a generic `List<Car>` as then you won't have to cast the objects later on.

Comment: It works to write out the values. But if i add for example two cars to the ArrayList, it writes out the same values for each object.

Comment: You'll have to include that in the for loop, of course. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Still not working. I still get the same values written to the Console. If i use the arraylist.Insert(index, object) method, does it replace the previous object at that index or does it make the old object to move to i + 1?

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList is not a generic collection.  ArrayList indexing returns an object value.  To do what you want you would have to cast Cars[i] to a Car type.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Cars.Count; i++)
  {
     Console.WriteLine((Car)Cars[i].carBrand);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `ArrayList` contains `Object`  items and so you have to filter out `Car` items:

```
// I suggest creating a "report" string which is more flexible then loop:
// you can show the report in console, write into file etc. in one line    
String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, cars
  .OfType<Car>()                 // Cars only
  .Select(car => car.carBrand)); // Brand from each car

// Just one simple line
Console.WriteLine(report);
```

P.S. `ArrayList` is an *obsolete* class, try using `List<Car>` instead